# Input text control disappears on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have a few Input Controls (text) created in the code-behind in this manner as part of dynamic RadiobuttonList (so that a textbox is next to a radiobutton):

```
RadioButtonList radioOption = new RadioButtonList();

 radiobuttonlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt.Rows[i][9].ToString() + " <input id=\"" + name + "\" runat=\"server\" type=\"text\" value=\"Enter text\" />")
```

All the controls are within UpdatePanel.

Everytime there is postback, the text within the Input control disappears.

How do I keep the input text values?

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The control tree must be rebuilt on **every** postback, including partial postbacks - or let it rebuild through ControlState/ViewState. In this case, in subsequent postbacks, the Items collection is not rebuilt (or is cleared) and is empty during the Render phase.

For cases like this I would approach it as:

1. Enable ViewState on the RadioButtonList *and* ensure it is added no later than Load<sup>1</sup>, or;
2. Store the ViewState of an appropriate Collection on the container control and then DataBind the consuming control - see [GenericDataSourceControl](http://genericdatasource.codeplex.com/) for a clean way to set this up. I prefer this approach as it's consistent, predictable, and easy to control.

---

<sup>1</sup>This *ought* to work but it might not. I am usually confused as to which controls *really* support ViewState and to what extent as the usage always strikes me as .. inconsistent. In any case, it *won't* work if ViewState is disabled - remember that disable ViewState for the page (or parent control) disables ViewState all the way down. Also, the control *must* be loaded into the Control Tree at the appropriate time *and* with the same Control Path/ID  (usually Init or Load) so that it will correctly function with the request ViewState.

---

Rough idea for #2:

Save the view state in the containing user control (must have ViewState enabled for this control):

```
// ListItem is appropriately serializable and works well for
// automatic binding to various list controls.
List<ListItem> Names {
    // May return null
    get { return (List<ListItem>)ViewState["names"]; }
    set { ViewState["names"] = value; }
}
```

In the GenericDataSourceControl (put the GDS into the Markup so it has a nice ID) Select Event:

```
void SelectEvent(sender e, GenericSelectArgs args) {
   args.SetData(Names);
}
```

Add the RadioButtonList dynamically (say, in `Control.OnLoad`):

```
// Unless this NEEDS to be dynamic, move it into the declarative markup.
// The dynamic control must be added to the *same location* it was before the
// postback or there will be ugly invalid control tree creation exceptions.
var radioList = new RadioButtonList();
someControl.Controls.Add(radioList);
// To minimize problem with Control Tree creation this should be unique and
// consistent for dynamic controls.
radioList.ID = "radioList";

// Binding to the DS "declarative" usually works better I've found
radioList.DataSourceID = "idOfTheGDS";
// You -may- need to DataBind, depending upon a few factors - I will usually call
// DataBind in PreRender, but generally in the Load is OK/preferred.
// If it already binds, don't call it manually.
radioList.DataBind();
```

If DataBinding is working correctly then it should be possible to *disable* ViewState for the RadioButtonList .. but sometimes ViewState is used when ControlState should have been, so make sure it functions as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much pst - I will give option 1 a go and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I am trying option 2 right now (option 1 doesn't work). GenericDataSourceControl seems very complicated to do. Is there an easier way around it to "Store the ViewState of an appropriate Collection on the container control and then DataBind the consuming control"? Thanks!!!

Comment: @viv_acious That's (#2) the most consistent approach I've found - it has the added advantage of separating the view and the model (somewhat). It's only complicated the first few times - then it's an easy pattern.

Comment: Thanks pst - I'm really a asp.net newbie so all that is quite hard to understand. Would it work to just enable ViewState, store each input text in ViewState["name"] etc? Do you have any examples?

Comment: It's just really hard to search for input controls examples online...guess not many use it anymore!

Comment: @viv_acious I added a rough approach.

Comment: thanks sooooo much pst! really appreciate your time and help as i've been stuck with this for a while - will give it a go now :)

Comment: Hi pst - have tried and this approach is not working for me as I already have many other dynamic controls on the page and it's making things very complicated. Do you know if theres any other way around this without using GenericDataSourceControl?

Comment: Maybe I can somehow use TextBox instead of Input inside the RadiobuttonList? Do you know any ways to add textboxes within radiobuttonlist listitems? Thanks!!!

Comment: @viv_acious No, I do not now how to put a TextBox inside a RadioList. I would firs start by reducing the number of dynamic controls - but they all function the same (eve if not using the GDS). The controls *must* be added on a postback such that the original control tree is correctly restored (including control names) - *everything* ultimately derives from this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26993/discussion-between-viv-acious-and-pst)

Comment: so far, i've added the assembly etc, but I can't get the SelectEvent function to work. Where exactly do I put that? Thanks!

Comment: @viv_acious In the markup for the GDS Control in the User control/page is the easiest (it will work the the `DataSourceID` then). It's an event that's wired up. The GDS documentation should give an example.

Comment: thanks - in my code-behind on the function: void SelectEvent(sender e, GenericSelectArgs args){}, the text GenericSelectArgs is underlined with error saying the namespace GenericDataSourceControl cannot be found. I put the downloaded assembly all in the bin folder.  Is that correct?

Comment: @viv_acious Yes. Also make sure to Add the Reference.

Comment: THANK YOU - that's the reason!

Comment: I'm not quite sure when yourefer to the container user control in your example above. I am using a UpdatePanel to contain ALL the dynamic controls I have on the page. Is that what you mean by the container control? I really apologize for all the questions that I have - it's not easy to find examples online for this!

Comment: Surely there must be another way to save the user input text, and then on postback, bind it back to the input control? i don't mind if its messier! ;)